# Python 3 number guessing game

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

I created a simple number guessing game, but every time I don't type in a number the system crashes. Can someone please help!

```
import random

randNum = random.randint(1, 100)
guesses = 0

for i in range(1, 8):
    guesses = guesses + 1
    print("hi human guess a number 1-100! \n")
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess > randNum:
        print("your guess is too high")

    elif guess < randNum:
        print("your guess is too low")

    elif guess == randNum:
        print("duuude you're a genius \n")
        print("you needed " + str(guesses) + " guesses")
```

Comment: The error message states clearly what's not working. You need to use `==` for testing equality. `=` is the assignment operator. Also do not post images of code or stacktraces.

Comment: Could you please post your code as text?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are absolutely useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system crashes because Python cannot typecast characters to integers when you type cast them. You should explicitly write a condition to check for characters i.e. if the input string is anything except numbers, your code should print something like **"Try Again"** or **"Invalid Input"**.

```
import random

randNum = random.randint(1, 100)
guesses = 0

for i in range(1, 8):
    guesses = guesses + 1
    print("hi human guess a number 1-100! \n")
    guess = input()

    if guess.isdigit():
        if int(guess) > randNum:
            print("your guess is too high \n")

        elif int(guess) < randNum:
            print("your guess is too low \n")

        elif int(guess) == randNum:
            print("duuude you're a genius \n")
            print("you needed " + str(guesses) + " guesses")

    else:
        print("Invalid Input! Try a number. \n")
```

Try this code. I hope it helps. And from next time try to upload code instead of images. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at your code and one thing which stands out is that on Line 10, you cast the input to an int without checking if the input is indeed an int.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def game():
    computer = random.randint(1, 10)
    # print(computer)
    user = int(input("Please guess a number between 1-10: "))
    count = 0



    while count < 5:
        if computer > user:
            count += 1
            print("You guessed too low!")
            print("You have used " + str(count) + "/5 guesses")
            user = int(input("Please guess a number another number!: "))

        elif computer < user:
            count += 1
            print("You guessed too high!")
            print("You have used " + str(count) + "/5 guesses")
            user = int(input("Please guess a number another number: "))
        else:
            print("YOU WON!!")
            again = input("Would you like to play again?")
            if again in["n", "No", "N", "no"]:
                break
            elif again in["y", "Yes", "Y", "yes"]:
                pass
                game()
        if count == 5:
            print("Bummer, nice try...the number was actually " + str(computer) + "!")
            again = input("Would you like to play again?")
            if again in["n", "No", "N", "no"]:
                break
            elif again in["y", "Yes", "Y", "yes"]:
                pass
                game()
            else:
                print("I'm sorry that's an invalid entry! Restart the game to try again!")

game()
```

Comment: Please add some description to what changes were made from original.